# greendao: way to debug queries?

Tags: android, greendao

Is there any way to make [greendao](http://greendao-orm.com/) spit queries that're being carried out into Logcat? I just want to reassure everything's working fine and it would be a good feature to have while getting accustomed to the system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The class QueryBuilder has a static flag for this:

```
/** Set to true to debug the SQL. */
public static boolean LOG_SQL;
```

So just set *QueryBuilder.LOG_SQL = true*, and you should get what you want.

Comment: does it work for all queries? because when I set it like `QueryBuilder.LOG_SQL = true;
  scheduleDao.queryBuilder().LOG_SQL = true;
  scheduleDao.insertOrReplaceInTx(dbSchedules);
`
it doesn't make any difference

Comment: No, it's just for queries.

Comment: does it work only on a real device? Because I've tried it on the Android Simulator but it does not log anything

Answer (score 4):

```
            dao.queryBuilder().LOG_VALUES=true; (For values)
            dao.queryBuilder().LOG_SQL=true;     (For query)
```